# What is it the max_length in the password of Django User?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

My problem is that I don't feel sure because I don't understand how work the password field in Django, that is to say, I think that this field hasn't got any max_length and it can be attacked with a buffer overflow. Is this possible?

I am using the default Django User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's default User model (`django.contrib.auth`) authenticates via username and password as stated in [docs](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/sep/15/security/).

> The raw password is not stored in the database; instead, a hashed
>   version of the password is stored, and the hash is computed each time
>   a user attempts to log in.

The default password hasher is *computing expensive* to increase the difficulty of attacks which use brute-force methods.

> Django does not impose any maximum on the length of the plaintext
>   password, meaning that an attacker can simply submit arbitrarily large
>   -- and guaranteed-to-fail -- passwords, forcing a server running Django to perform the resulting expensive hash computation in an
>   attempt to check the password. A password one megabyte in size, for
>   example, will require roughly one minute of computation to check when
>   using the PBKDF2 hasher.
>
> This allows for denial-of-service attacks through repeated submission
>   of large passwords, tying up server resources in the expensive
>   computation of the corresponding hashes.

And in the proper model, `django.contrib.auth.base_user` password field is defined with `max_length=128`.

```py
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
```

Comment: I don't get to launch this error when I exced the 4096 bytes. Do you know how can I launch this error? I count the number bytes in a UTF-8 counter web and I introduce 55.000 bytes I don't get the error

Comment: But the `max_length` in the DB is meaningless here b/c the value that goes into the DB is the hash of the password, not the password itself. Kind of some bad q's and a's here.

Answer (score 1):

i found in it:

> [To remedy this, Django's authentication framework will now automatically fail authentication for any password exceeding 4096 bytes](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/sep/15/security/)

If you only care password in `User` model it maybe 191. Read this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model

Comment: Could you put those links as links instead of code?

Answer (score 1):

The [Sep 2013 Django blog post](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/sep/15/security/) is being quoted here but [similar to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913501/what-is-it-the-max-length-in-the-password-of-django-user#comment100383566_56913823), I couldn't trigger the error. After some digging, it looks like [they reverted the max-length commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/5d74853) within the same month of that post.

Reading the commit message, they said they updated their pbkdf2 implementation and concluded a max length on the passwords was no longer necessary.

If you are still concerned and want to add a max-length check on user passwords, you can [create a Validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-validator) (I tested with a copy of the [MinimumLengthValidator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py#L91) and changed lines where appropriate). This Validator should then be added to your `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` list in your settings file.